# WordPress/Timber post loop looping four times

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

I have the following code in my theme's index.php file. It is set to grab four of the most recent posts from a selection of category IDs. The IDs are a mix of parent and children categories.

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '7,5,3,4,6',
    'numberposts' => 4,
    'order' => 'DESC',
);
$context['stories'] = Timber::get_posts($args);
```

The following code is used in the tease.twig file.

```
{% block content %}
    {{ post.content }}
{% endblock %}
```

The following code is used in the tease-stories.twig file.

```
{% extends "tease.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for story in stories %} 
        <article class="story" id="story-{{post.ID}}">
            {% if loop.first %}
                {% if story.thumbnail.src %}
                    <img src="{{story.thumbnail.src}}" class="" alt="" />
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %} 
            <h3 class="story__heading">
                <a href="{{ story.link }}">
                    {{ story.title }}
                </a>
            </h3>
            <div class="story__meta">
                <time class="">{{ story.date }}</time>
            </div>
            {% if loop.first %}
            <div class="story__content">
                {{ story.preview.read_more(false) }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

The following code is used in the index.twig file.

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
<section class="stories">
    <h2>Latest Travel Stories</h2>
    {% for story in stories %}
        {% include ['tease-stories.twig'] %}
    {% endfor %}
</section>

<section class="observations">
    <h2>Observations</h2>
    {% for observation in observations %}
        {% include ['tease-observations.twig'] %}
    {% endfor %}
    <a href="{{ site.url }}/gerry/observations" title="More observations" class="more more-observations">
        More Observations
    </a>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Screenshot of looped content:

[image: looped content]

I am not sure why the loop is looping over the content four times. Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: How did you verify this behavior? Perhaps it's the collection that is wrong to start with. U could verify the amount of items with `{{ stories | length }}` to start with

Comment: Are you using the timber starter theme?

Comment: @DarkBee The screenshot shows how the HTML is rendered and outputted by WordPress/Timber/Twig. `{{ stories | length }}` returns **4**, but is displayed four times on the rendered page. It looks like WordPress is selecting four posts, but Timber/Twig are looping through those posts four different times.

Comment: @Jainil Yes, I started with the starter theme from Timber and have been customizing it to my client's needs.

Comment: That's all of the `twig` you are using?

Comment: @DarkBee I have updated my question with the code used in my index.twig file.

Comment: You don't need the `for`-loop in your `index` as you are looping the collection already in `tease-stories`

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for pointing that out. I have removed the `for loop` code and it is now functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with assistance from @DarkBee. The problem was using a `for loop` twice, once in the index.twig file and once in the tease.twig file, which resulted in the stories being outputted multiple times. My updated index.twig code is below.

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
<section class="stories">
    <h2>Latest Travel Stories</h2>
    {% include ['tease-stories.twig'] %}
</section>

<section class="observations">
    <h2>Observations</h2>
    {% include ['tease-observations.twig'] %}
    <a href="{{ site.url }}/gerry/observations" title="More observations" class="more more-observations">
        More Observations
    </a>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```